# Web scraper returning list of elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, mechanize, lxml

I'm trying to build a scraper that scrapes information from the tables on multiple webpages via mechanize and lxml. The code below is returning a list of elements, I'm trying to find a way to get the the text from these elements (adding .text doesn't work on a list object)

The code is as follows:

```
import mechanize
import lxml.html as lh
import csv

br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("http://localhost/allproducts")

output = csv.writer(file(r'output.csv','wb'), dialect='excel')

for link in br.links(url_regex="product"):
    follow = br.follow_link(link)
    url = br.response().read()
    find = lh.document_fromstring(url)
    find = find.findall('.//td')
    print find
    output.writerows([find])
```

If I add the following to the end of the code above the text from the tds appear in the csv file but the text from each td appears on a separate line, I'd like the format to be the same as for the code above just with the text rather than a list of elements (all information from each page is on a single line)

```
for find in find:
    print find.text
    output.writerows([find.text])
```

I took the code from a bunch of other examples, so any general recommendations are also much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close! Theres 2 problems with your code:

1) find is a list of Objects, not a list of strings. Here's some python to verify this:

```
>>> type(find)
<type 'list'>
>>> find
[<Element td at 0x101401e30>, <Element td at 0x101401e90>, <Element td at 0x101401ef0>, <Element td at 0x101401f50>, <Element td at 0x101401fb0>, <Element td at 0x101404050>, <Element td at 0x1014040b0>, <Element td at 0x101404110>, <Element td at 0x101404170>, <Element td at 0x1014041d0>, <Element td at 0x101404230>, <Element td at 0x101404290>, <Element td at 0x1014042f0>, <Element td at 0x101404350>, <Element td at 0x1014043b0>, <Element td at 0x101404410>]
>>> type(find[0])
<class 'lxml.html.HtmlElement'>
```

We would say that the `find` variable points to a list of `<class 'lxml.html.HtmlElement'>` objects. This type of structure shouldn't be passed directly to `output.writerows`. Instead, this function will take a list of text items.

2) When iterating over the `find` object, you're re-assigning the variable name `find`. Never use the same name when iterating as the name of the item you're iterating over!

```
for item in find:
    print item.text
    output.writerows([item.text])
```

Putting it all together, you should have something like this:

```
for link in br.links(url_regex="product"):
    follow = br.follow_link(link)
    url = br.response().read()
    find = lh.document_fromstring(url)
    find = find.findall('.//td')
    print find
    results = []  # Create a place to store the text names
    for item in find:
        results.append(item.text)  # Store the text name of the item in the results list.
    output.writerows(results)  # Now, write the results out.  # EDITED to use correct variable here.
```

**A pro tip**

You could even generate the results as a one-liner using list comprehension, like this:

```
results = [item.text for item in find]
output.writerows(results)
```

This would replace 3 lines of python with a single line.

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much for this. The only change in the code above needed was to change output.writerows([find.text]) to output.writerows([results]), the code in the pro tip worked perfectly first time